# How to prevent ActivityViewController from appending 'www' to shared link

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I have an issue where the link being shared within the ActivityViewController is prepended with 'www' when sharing to 'Messages'. This breaks the link because the url is meant to direct to a non-www website.

The link going into activity items is as follows:

`"https://mag*****.com/@\(mag.publisher.username)/\(mag.slug)"`

Then turns into this:

`"https://www.mag****.com/@Art_Collective/the-goal-of-angels-****"`

What I mean by sharing into 'Messages':

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you would just accept the `www`. Excluding `www` when there is no other prefix is poor practice in any case.

Comment: So our web dev has now added the `www` to the accepted urls for the site. I have added the url with `www` to the Associated Domains list within the Xcode project Signing & Capabilities. It still doesn't work and I thought I read somewhere that the app needs to be submitted to App Store Connect to recognize these changes, is that correct?

Comment: What does "it still doesn't work" mean?

Comment: When I send a link to myself via text message, I then click on it, it brings up the web address in Safari. It does not bring up the iOS app itself.

Comment: Good answer. So this is intended to be a Universal Link but it isn't one. So my guess is that universal links are just not configured correctly for this app. You can test that easily enough right on the Simulator; there's a way in the Terminal to throw a Universal Link at the system and see what it does. But that would then be an issue about Universal Links in general, and nothing to do with the Activity View Controller.